# Timer (output compare mode) not working on stm32f411re

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, timer

I am using an stm32f411re nucleo board. I am trying to configure the Tim2_ch1 module in output compare mode.

I have written the code by referring to the reference manual:

https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00119316-stm32f411xc-e-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

code:

```
//PA5:TIM2_CH1

// clock frequency:16Mhz

 

#include "stm32f4xx.h"         // Device header

// toggle led at 1hz using TIM2 output COMPARE MODE

int main(void)

{

 RCC->AHB1ENR |=1;

GPIOA->MODER |=0X800; //PA_5 is configured in alternate function mode

GPIOA->AFR[0] |=0X00100000; // Tim2_ch1 is assigned to PA_5


//TIM2 OUTPUT COMPARE CONFIG

RCC->APB1ENR |=1;

TIM2->PSC |=1600-1;   

TIM2->ARR |=10000-1;   //clock frequency is divided by prescalar and auto reload

TIM2->CCMR1 |=0X30;    

TIM2->CCR1 |=0;

TIM2->CCER |=1;

TIM2->CNT |=0;

TIM2->CR1 |=1;


while(1)

{}


}
```

This code is not working. Is there any issue with the code?

Comment: Do you really mean to use the `|=` (OR-equals) operator for every register assignment?  That seems wrong for TIM2->PSC, TIM2->ARR, and probably others but I stopped checking.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't look like to be anything wrong with the assignments of the regsiters.
I believe the right bits are being set. Magic numbers don't help.
*Please use the defines in the header file. eg: `RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN`*

Although `TIM2->CNT |=0;` doesn't make sense.

I suspect the problem is with the `RCC->APB1ENR |=1;` and the other RCC write.  You need at least one APB clock delay to ensure it is actually set before doing anything else.  Simple way to do that is to read it back.

Snippet from STM32 LL library:

```
__STATIC_INLINE void LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock(uint32_t Periphs)
{
  __IO uint32_t tmpreg;
  SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, Periphs);
  /* Delay after an RCC peripheral clock enabling */
  tmpreg = READ_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, Periphs);
  (void)tmpreg;
}
// __IO expands to the volatile keyword
```

Comment: thanks for your help @jeroen3